# SSRS 2008 Error Message. What does it mean?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Anyone have a clue what this error message means?

```
An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. native compiler 
return value ‘128’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

128
 Error
 Activation
 Report Server
 Reporting Services components from different editions cannot be used together.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165307.aspx

Comment: Much obliged. Google kept giving me useless results. Thanks!