# Errors when processing RDLC reports

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, process, report, rdlc

I am getting the following error when doing load test of a page which renders a

```
An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: 
The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid. ---> 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: 
An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘128’.
```

This page works fine initially and then fails.

Any thoughts appreciated.

I tried running the IIS under LocalSystem account. Still I am getting the same exception.

**Update:
I tracked this issue and found that the problem is caused when the Report Viewer compiles the report using Visual Basic compiler. To be more accurate, this error code is Windows Error code and not the Reporting Services error code (There are no child processes to wait for).
I tried to reproduce the same scenario, but with no luck.**

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have conflicting versions/editions somewhere. Check that your versions and dependencies are of the same version.

See here: [SSRS 2008 Error Message. What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470718/ssrs-2008-error-message-what-does-it-mean)

And Here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165307.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Today, I got a similar error using MS SQL 2012 and .Net Framework 3.5

All reports containing an expression failed to compiled showing a native compiler error value: 2146234076

I updated to .net Framework 4.5 and the issue dissappeared with no reconfiguration needed.